# Is this proper usage of AmplifyRequireNewPassword React component?

Tags: aws-amplify-sdk-js

The intent of my app is to log in to a AWS Cognito User Pool where new users are created by the admin and sent a temporary password.

The user pool was created with the Amplify CLI.

This code is pretty much copied and pasted from the AWS Amplify documentation:

```
import React from "react";
import Amplify from "aws-amplify";
import { AmplifyAuthenticator, AmplifyRequireNewPassword } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
import awsconfig from "./aws-exports";
import './App.css';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

function App() {
  return (
      <AmplifyAuthenticator>
          <AmplifyRequireNewPassword
              headerText="My Custom Require New Password Text"
              slot="require-new-password"
          ></AmplifyRequireNewPassword>
          Logged In
      </AmplifyAuthenticator>
  );
}

export default App;
```

After creating a new user in the Cognito console, on a test run of the app I successfully signed in and was prompted to change my password. However, when I submitted the new password, I was presented with the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'completeNewPasswordChallenge' of undefined
```

The browser was Microsoft Edge 86.0

Answer (score 0):

I notice you're not passing the user object, but that's not a guarantee to fix it.  I'm running into the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was dropping the explicit reference to AmplifyRequireNewPassword. I didn't really need custom text.